# Unable to KeyboardInterrupt while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, error-handling, while-loop

I have a python script that runs on an infinite loops. In the loop multiprocess and async functions happen so normally I catch KeyboardInterrupt to properly kill all the processes.

Using similar code somehow on one of the loops I am unable to catch the KeyboardInterrupt the loop just keeps going.

logic goes like that:

```
try:
    while True:
         do stuff
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    exit cleanly
```

Normally I would suspect a blanket try ... except somewhere in the children functions but I went over the whole code base and while there is a lot of error catching everything is specific.

Is there a way to trace errors and somehow figure out where the KeyboardInterrupt is caught ?

Thank you

****** Edit after some debugging...
So I disabled the code part by part until I cornered the bug:
Somewhere in the code I was calling a method that was missing self and was not marked as @staticmethod.

Changing that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
try:
    while True:
        print(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    raise
```

EDIT:
Actually read your question, I won't be able to tell you why it's not raising an error without seeing the rest or more of the code.